# how to make half a day available in easepick datepicker

Tags: html, datepicker, calendar

I want to have preselected dates in easepick example saturday to saturday booking.  i want to show a half day available with a half triangle as checkout is 10am and check in is 4pm.

How can i make them only to select a saturday to start the 7 day selection?

I tried adding the time formats of MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:SS but it wouldn't allow saturday to be picked.